# Preserve stats page view (votes, newest, views, recent)

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, views

When I click on stats, it always sorts by votes.
But usually it would be interesting to see that data maybe just once in a month.

Would it not be nice to preserve view state to last one or default it to "recent" ?

Thank you.